# Build a tallest tower by stacking the various blocks?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I came across below interview question and I am not able to understand what needs to be done here?

> Suppose you are trying to build a very tall tower. You have a
>   collection of blocks to make your tower out of. For each block type,
>   you are given the number of blocks you have of that type, its weight,
>   and the maximum weight that block can support above it and including
>   itself. Suppose (for now) that all blocks have the same height (1
>   meter). What's the tallest tower you can construct by stacking these
>   blocks?

Below is the example input, with each row representing a block type, of format "  "

```
1   1  1
10  2  10
100 3  100
```

And the output should be: 35

What's the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation of the knapsack problem:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

It‘s a classical example of dynamic programming. I won‘t write down the algorithm here because countless people who are better at explaining it than I am have before me, the wikipedia article on it is certainly a good start.